# Tell AFHTTPClient to add trailing slash automatically

Tags: django, afnetworking

I'm using `AFHTTPClient` to make requests to a Django+Tastypie app. This app has the `APPEND_SLASH` setting enabled, which means that if the URL doesn't end with a trailing slash, the request is redirected to the same URL with the slash appended.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
[[AFHTTPClient sharedClient] getPath:@"entry" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {            

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}];
```

The resulting URL is `http://www.example.com/api/v1/entry`, which gets redirected to `http://www.example.com/api/v1/entry/`. Is there any way to tell `AFHTTPClient` to always add a trailing slash automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either

1. Always provide the trailing `/` in your `getPath:` argument (like `getPath:@"entry/"`), or
2. Subclass `AFHTTPClient` with a method that adds it.

Here's an example of #2:

```
- (void)getPath:(NSString *)path 
     parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters 
        success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
        failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
{
    if ([path length] > 0 && ![path hasSuffix:@"/"])
        path = [path stringByAppendingString:@"/"];

    [super getPath:path parameters:parameters success:success failure:failure];
}
```